# Close a socket connection with PHP

Tags: php, sockets

I have a script that opens a port and allows socket communication between multiple connections (a simple flash chat-box). This script has had to take care of itself regarding how long to run for and when to close the port. My question is, in case this script gets caught in an infinite loop (or I otherwise lose control of it) what can I do to close the port?

To be clear on this, I am after a second php script that will force close the port the first script has opened (I can then put some check code into this script to stop executing if the socket has been closed).

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  Ordinarily, sockets are open until they are closed by the program or the program crashes/exits.  Usually you have some kind of communication protocol that says, "hey this is the end of our conversation, now please close your socket down."  Also, if your program is liable to encounter an infinite loop, you either need to reconsider your design or put some kind of check system that will avert infinite loops.

Comment: Are you trying to do this because when you try to re-run your script you get an error that the port is already in use even though your script has terminated?

Comment: @kevin628 I have a chat box where I am using PHP as a server.  The script opens the port and, inside of a `while(1):` loop, listens for and manages connections. There is a check in the loop to say after an hour close the connection. While this works, I would like a way to force close a connection from a separate script.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King I'm not aware of a way to do that.  A socket exists within the instance it was created.  If you create the socket and run the `while(1)` loop inside script "foo.php", as far as I know, there's no way for a separate execution of another script, say "bar.php" to access the socket created in foo.php and close it down.  Typically, client-server applications rely on threading to achieve socket pooling and monitoring.

Comment: @kevin628 Please make that an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do that. A socket exists within the instance it was created. If you create the socket and run the `while(1)` loop inside script "foo.php", as far as I know, there's no way for a separate execution of another script, say "bar.php" to access the socket created in foo.php and close it down. Typically, client-server applications rely on threading to achieve socket pooling and monitoring.